# Pen click is backward on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, stylus

I am running Windows 7 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X220 Tablet. After getting a new pen for the device today, it has been working fine.

However, with no known changes, the clicking has been "reversed." Now, the tip will show the location on the screen (that is, with the small pointer indicator on the screen) but will not click upon pressing, whereas the back end, with the red eraser type tip, is what will click and draw on the screen. I have tried reinstalling the Lenovo drivers for the Wacom digitzer, but this has not shown any effects.

I have tried disabling the eraser feature, but this does not help with the problem.

Here are the settings in the control panel:

[image: Pen1]
[image: Pen2]

I have also tried calibrating the pen, but it does not recognize the clicks there, either.

Comment: Disconnect the pen, remove and install the batteries, then connect the pen again.

Comment: Did not work. As a workaround, was able to disable the eraser and switch to mode of only clicking when the pen is near and the right button is clicked, but it does not work on tap.